# Send mail only once at a day/at a time

Tags: c#, email

I am developing a code of,sending mail to the database email id's

This is the page load in aspx.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        loadEmp_Emailid();
    }
}
```

after in loadEmp_Emailid() function having this code in bellow

```
protected void loadEmp_Emailid()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select email from emailtable", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    int size_arr = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    string[] arr = new string[size_arr];
    int i = 0;
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds_.Tables[0].Rows) 
        {
            arr[i] = dr["email"].ToString();
            if (dr["email"].ToString() == "")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                sendmail(arr[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

The above code i am getting 10 email ids like

```
test@gmail.com
test1@gmail.com
test2@gmail.com
test3@gmail.com
test4@gmail.com
test5@gmail.com
.............
..............
```

here is the send mail function

```
public  void sendmail(string emailTo)
{
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    smtpClient.Host = "smtp.247headhunting.com";
    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@test.com", "xxxxx");
    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@test.com", "XXXXXX");
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage Message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    Message.From = From;
    Message.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(emailTo));
    Message.Subject = "Subject ";
    Message.Body = "Testing";
    Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    try
    {
        smtpClient.Send(Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        Message.Dispose();
    }
}
```

here is the problem is each page load time the mail is sending...

I don't want to send more more then one time in a day without using page load concept 
i want send automatically please give me the any suggestion please

Thanks 
 pradeep

Comment: Just store in the database when you last sent them. But I have a question: if it's a scheduled operation why you do it in an ASP.NET page? Isn't better a scheduled task? Moreover don't forget to dispose disposable objects (like SQL connection, command and reader).

Comment: i don't how to developed scheduled task can u please give me suggestion... Adriano

Comment: Just a suggestion: it is considered a good idea not reading right from tables but instead use views, SPs and functions (and block access to tables...). It would also be better to STUFF the items and get all mail addresses in one go and one row. Related to the question, I'm with @Adriano - store it in the DB...

Answer (score 1):

Don't execute batch jobs from your ASP.NET pages. You can instead use a specialized scheduler like the [Quartz.NET enterprise scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) (open-source).

You can have a look at the [Quick start guide](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/index.html) and the [various tutorials](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/index.html).

**Note:** the basic idea is to host your quartz.net server as a windows service, alongside your asp.net website. Hosting quartz.net *inside* an asp.net website might be a bad idea (non-predictibility of app pool recycling may lead to unexpected behavior for instance).

Answer (score 0):

For ScheduleTask first build a simple Console-Application witch loads the Email from the database and sends the message over the smtpClient.

Than follow [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-windows-task-scheduler.html).

I hope it helps.